# Artifactory Rest API (Quick Search) - What is the correct usage of wildcards when specifying "repos"?

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to use the Artifactory Quick Search API (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactSearch(QuickSearch)) to find the URL to a given artifact while giving it the repo parameter with a wildcard in it. I can only get a result when the repo value is an exact match.

Artifacts are being loaded with these generic properties: 
build.name (IE:Enterprise-Communications :: NativeVXML-CICD-TestDemo :: v1.2.7rc)
build.number (IE: 1)
build.timestamp (unix time stamp)
tag    (Git tag version number)
vcs.revision  (think it's git's commit_id)

I can't recall all of the sites and pages I've checked but here is one that shows the UI using * and ? as wildcards.
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API

Our company Artifactory is geo-redundant and using a root directory naming convention of [Department]-[purpose]-[environment], so something like "SysDev-general-dev" and "SysDev-general-prod" with a pipeline process of copying the file from -dev into -prod once QA/UAT acceptance is complete.

The artifact is uploaded to a repo/folder of "SysDev-general-dev/clientName/program/artifact.tar" and apparently the system is then adding a "-[Site]" reference to the repo ("SysDev-general-dev-DEN01"), but that site identifier is only visible when logged into one of the site specific UIs or using the search APIs.

---

** Note: tests done with Chrome, FireFox, and Ansible playbook w/ 'uri'
module.

When performing a Quick Search with the artifact name, it returns a list of URLs as expected.
"artifactory/api/search/artifact?name=NativeVXML-CICD-TestDemo.v1.2.7"

`{
  "results" : [ {
    "uri" : "http://<DOMAIN>/artifactory/api/storage/Enterprise-Communications-generic-preprod-SWN01/nreddy/NativeVXML-CICD-TestDemo/NativeVXML-CICD-TestDemo.v1.2.7.tar"
  }, {
    "uri" : "http://<DOMAIN>/artifactory/api/storage/Enterprise-Communications-generic-prod-SWN01/nreddy/NativeVXML-CICD-TestDemo/NativeVXML-CICD-TestDemo.v1.2.7.tar"
  } ]
}`

---

Using repo filter with exact match returns the 1 URI that I want.
&repos=Enterprise-Communications-generic-preprod-SWN01
`{
  "results" : [ {
    "uri" : "http://<DOMAIN>/artifactory/api/storage/Enterprise-Communications-generic-preprod-SWN01/nreddy/NativeVXML-CICD-TestDemo/NativeVXML-CICD-TestDemo.v1.2.7.tar"
  } ]
}`

---

When adding "&repos=" with the first piece of the root dir to filter the return, an empty result set is returned.
"artifactory/api/search/artifact?name=NativeVXML-CICD-TestDemo.v1.2.7.tar&repos=Enterprise-Communications-generic-preprod"

`{
  "results" : [ ]
}`

---

Add * to wildcard repo name:
"artifactory/api/search/artifact?name=NativeVXML-CICD-TestDemo.v1.2.7.tar&repos=Enterprise-Communications-generic-preprod"
`{
  "results" : [ ]
}`

---

Wrap repo name (with *) in quotes
artifactory/api/search/artifact?name=NativeVXML-CICD-TestDemo.v1.2.7.tar&repos="Enterprise-Communications-generic-preprod*"
`{
  "results" : [ ]
}`

---

Wrap repo name (with *) in quotes and URL encode:
artifactory/api/search/artifact?name=NativeVXML-CICD-TestDemo.v1.2.7.tar&repos=%22Enterprise-Communications-generic-preprod%A2%22
`{
  "results" : [ ]
}`

---

Wrap repo name (with ?) in quotes
artifactory/api/search/artifact?name=NativeVXML-CICD-TestDemo.v1.2.7.tar&repos="Enterprise-Communications-generic-preprod?"
`{
  "results" : [ ]
}`

Playbook:

`- name: "Search URL: {{find_uri}} "
      uri:
        url: '{{ find_uri }}'
        method: GET               # Default is GET
        force_basic_auth: yes
        validate_certs: no
        return_content: yes
        timeout: 15               #Default is 30
      register: artifact_list`

What I really want to do is pass in a repo reference with a wild card and get only URI values back that contain that value.

IE: &repos="Enterprise-Communications-generic-preprod*"

`{
  "results" : [ {
    "uri" : "http://<DOMAIN>/artifactory/api/storage/Enterprise-Communications-generic-preprod-SWN01/nreddy/NativeVXML-CICD-TestDemo/NativeVXML-CICD-TestDemo.v1.2.7.tar"
  } ]
}`

Comment: you can also use artifactory aql in case api is not giving expected results

Comment: Yes, I was looking into that but would prefer to not have to go that route.

Comment: ok I will check the api for wildcards and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Well, it isn't the way I'd prefer to do it but I did get a couple of simple Jinja statements to help me filter down the returned map of URLs.

```
- set_fact:
    artifact_url: "{{ (artifact_list.content | from_json ).results | map(attribute='uri') | select('match', artifact_root_dir) | list  }}" # will return a list or empty
    failed_when:  not artifact_url or artifact_url | length != 1    #fail when not set/empty or list contains more than 1
```